# How to access a maven repo on artifactory in gradle using API key?

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory, api-key

We have a JFrog artifactory that contains a maven repo (and other elements).

In my gradle setup, I defined this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("https://eu.artifactory....../whatever/")    
        credentials {
            username = "my-full-user-id"
            password = "my-real-password"
        }
    }
}
```

Works fine. It **also** works when I change the password entry to use my JFrog [API KEY](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/User+Profile).

But: using the api key only works when `username` contains my real user id.

Whereas: when making https requests "directly" to JFrog (for example using a python script), it is **not** required to provide a user name: simply having the API KEY in the request header is enough.

Thing is: in our setup, we have the API key at hand, but not the user id. So I had hoped to be able to define a maven dependency in gradle that works without user names.

But when

- I leave username blank in my gradle setup, gradle complains about it being null.
- I try anything else but my real user id, I get a `401 Unauthorized` response

Question: is it possible to use "maven style" repository definition in gradle that works with API KEYS and that doesn't need the corresponding user ids?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Artifactory supports header based authentication where you provide the API key in the header `X-JFrog-Art-Api` (see [Artifactory REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API)). I do not have an Artifactory instance at hand to test, but Gradle's [HTTP header authentication](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:http-header-auth) should do the trick:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2")
        credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials::class) {
            name = "Private-Token"
            value = "TOKEN"
        }
        authentication {
            create<HttpHeaderAuthentication>("header")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, this works. Well, the code you had in the answer gave me compilation errors, but the code you linked to worked better. So just copied that content into your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The answer with "Private-Token" does not work for me with Artifactory 7.41.

Instead, this is what worked:

```
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://<artifactory.server.fqdn>/artifactory/<maven-repo-name>"
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                name = "Authorization"
                value = "Bearer <token>"
            }
            authentication { header(HttpHeaderAuthentication) }
        }
    }
```